# Migrating from heroku to dokku (digital ocean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, digital-ocean

I'm switching everything from heroku off and moving to digital ocean (cheaper and a static ip address!!)

I have searchbox on heroku. And i'll be needing something like this on digital ocean.

Currently i'm hitting an error making a request (still setup for heroku?) That looks like this

```
I, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.226034 #275]  INFO -- : Started GET "/events_autocomplete?query=test" for 212.250.145.155 at 2016-06-22 13:18:41 +0000
I, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.253478 #275]  INFO -- : Processing by EventsController#autocomplete as JSON
I, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.253665 #275]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"query"=>"test"}
I, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.264460 #275]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (Searchkick: 5.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.266812 #275] FATAL -- :
Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:61:in `autocomplete'


I, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.319310 #275]  INFO -- : Started GET "/search_events?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=test&commit=Search" for 212.250.145.155 at 2016-06-22 13:18:41 +0000
I, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.321272 #275]  INFO -- : Processing by EventsController#search as HTML
I, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.321365 #275]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"test", "commit"=>"Search"}
I, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.326730 #275]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2016-06-22T13:18:41.328614 #275] FATAL -- :
Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:83:in `search'
```

I'm very new at this so any help would be much appreciated

Thanks
Sam

**Edit**

```
  def search
    @events = Event.where("event_type != 'festival' AND complete = true").page(params[:page]).per(10).search params[:search], suggest: true, misspellings: { distance: 1 }, order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc }, match: :word_start
    if @events.results.any?
      render 'events/results'
    else
      render 'events/noresults'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Add code around line 83 from your `app/controllers/events_controller.rb` file please.

Comment: Adding now , Not sure if you'll like it haha!

Comment: Do you have some sort of search technology set up? What is adding the `Event.search` method to your model? It's likely a gem, and it's likely trying to communicate to some sort of search server (Solr, Elastic Search, etc.) at `localhost:9200`. Can you look at `models/event.rb` and see if there is anything in there that would give you a hint? (That doesn't mean copy and paste your whole model file into this question.)

Comment: Hi Chris, Sorry for the delay, I have searchkick in my website

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official [dokku-elasticsearch](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-elasticsearch) plugin to setup an ES instance and link it to your application. Once you do, `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` will be set for your app and as long as your code respects that, you should be good to go.